# how many times a filter gets called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

assume a filter like

```
app.filter('unread', function () {
  return function (note) {
    console.log(note);
    return (note.status == 'unread');
  };
});
```

I use this filter on an array in $rootScope

```
<span ng-class="(note| unread).length == 0 ? '' : 'active'">{{value.length}}</span>
```

in which `$rootScope.note` is an array. the span element is outside of ng-view and it's not related to $scope and I have many arrays of objects in the $scope.

I thought that the filter would log the note in the number of $rootScope.note.length. but It logs much more of it and I can't figure out a reasonable relation between elements of $rootScope, $scope and the logs in the console. may you please explain about this?

### Edit:

filter corrected.

Comment: Why exactly are you using filter in this situation? The filter returns a boolean. Why do you call `length` on it?

Comment: @Sulthan yes, thank you. but I need to know why it's getting called 26 times instead of 6. even when I corrected as you said and it seems to work fine. at least the result is what I expected.

Comment: Why should it be called 6 times?

Comment: @zeroflagL because I have 6 notes in note array in $rootScope, not 26

Comment: why should it be evaluated only once for every directive?

Comment: @Sulthan directives? It's getting called 26 times - without any errors - but I expected 6 times, because I have 6 notes in $rootScope.note.

Comment: thats not how angular works. If you want to understand ehen it gets evaluated, put a breakpoint there and step through the code.

Comment: because you have error in your filter, it's getting called incorrect. first make sure your filter is getting called correctly then check if it's still working more than times you're expecting

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your html call to the filter incorrect ?
Try removing the `:note` like this :

```
<span ng-class="(note| unread).length == 0 ? '' : 'active'">{{value.length}}</span>
```

What's after the semicolon are additional arguments. For example if you wanted to filter important unread notes only :

```
app.filter('unread', function () {
  return function (note, type) {
    console.log(note);
    return (note.status == 'unread' && note.type == type);
  };
});

<span ng-class="(note| unread:'important').length == 0 ? '' : 'active'">{{value.length}}</span>
```